# FMod Memory Optimization

Tags: fmod, memory, optimizations, gameaudio

Hey there,

Does FMod Multitrack events, loads a sound def to memory only when it's called by the Multitrack Event, and, kills events when they aren't needed anymore?

Or does FMod load all the event sounds on the memory when event first called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is that when an event is called all of the associated sound defs will also be loaded. The data then sticks around until you call freeEventData.

support@fmod.org will typically reply to this kind of technical question pretty promptly.